# How to display a partial view based upon dropdown selection change event in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

What I want to do is, when user select any validation type from dropdown list, view for that particular validation type's view needs to display. How to display that particular view based upon dropdown selection change event. I also need go fill the model at same drop down change event.

What I have tried:

I have written a jquery code on drop down change event, but stuck how to display a partial view using jquery. Also it's showing model null while displaying a view. I am not able to fill the model at the change event of drop down.

Comment: you may invoke a AJAX request for partial view to MVC application and then replace some part of your page with response.

Comment: @vasily.sib,  Can you please help with some code sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if i do not understand wrong , you want to set  html element content with server side action content or set with partial content that will call directly. 
if you want to call server side action , you can write code like below;

```
$('#htmlelement').load('@Url.Action("CreateOUpdateUser")');
```

if you want the other option , you can write code like below;

```
 $('#htmlelement').load('@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/Login.cshtml", new GeosysPortal.Models.ViewModels.LoginVW())');
```

Comment: Hi Mehmet, thanks for help. I have tried the same code line in jquery dropdown change event. But while binding a model it is coming as a null. How to bind the model again based upon dropdown selection. Kindly help.

Comment: I dont know how to bind model with javascript, But as I said previously you can call server action , then action may bind model by your parameters . example ; $('#htmlelement').load('@Url.Action("CreateOUpdateUser")?selectedValues='+$("#select").val());